# What is the difference between "Create task with reference" and "Create task" in the Podio API?

Tags: podio, make.com

I would like to create a task with a reference to a specific workspace using "Make an API Call" in Make (Integromat).

Perhaps I should use "Create task with reference".

However, if you check the Podio API documentation, you will find that "ref_type" and "ref_id" also exist in the "Create task" Request, so it seems that you can create tasks with a reference to a object as well.

Which one should I use?